# Free to use Java phonetic password generator?

Tags: passwords, jvm, generator, phonetics

I'm looking for free to use phonetic/pronounceable password generator written in Java (or any JVM language, which can be called from Java).

Ideally the generator would accept criteria for the passwords it creates, eg:

- minimum length
- minimum number of non-alpha characters

This would be used in a commercial, distributed application, so the license must be compatible with this scenario.

Are there any out there?

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithm: Create a list of vowels and consonants. After adding a consonant to the password, also add a vowel.

Comment: Simple, but sub-optimal: "bababababa" would be a pretty bad password. It's an easy step to prevent this kind of password, but there will probably will be other bad cases after that, and if the work's been done already...

;-)